# MS Access: Hide object based on Table's field value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Microsoft Access report that is based directly on a table.  In that report I have an object, a line, that I have made invisible.

How do I make that line visible if a value in one of the table's fields is 100?

Answer (score 1):

The `Detail` section has a `Format` event, in which you can set the line to visible:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Line1.Visible = Field1 > 100
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that for more complex calculations the `Format` event may be triggered multiple times (depending on how many times Access has to recalculate the layout of the page, which will be affected by things like CanShrink and CanGrow). `FormatCount` has the number of the current call.

There is also a `Print` event which triggers before Access is actually ready to print/preview. One difference between the two is that `Print` will only be triggered if the section is actually going to be printed -- if you only print the last page of the report, the `Format` event will be triggered for all the previous sections, but not the `Print` event.

I assume the `Print` event would also not be triggered if you cancelled the `Format` event by saying `Cancel = True`.

References:

- [OnFormat property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844931.aspx)
- [OnPrint property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836969.aspx)

(I couldn't find documentation for the Format and Print events in the Access 2010 reference, because the documentation is sorted by object and these events belong to the hidden `_SectionInReport` object.)

- [Format event (Access XP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165406%28v=office.10%29.aspx)
- [Print event (Access XP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141179%28v=office.10%29.aspx)
- [What exactly is the difference between OnFormat and OnPrint?](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/difference-OnFormat-t1449302.html)

Comment: +1 Just mentioning that a table is not usually best for forms and reports, a query is usually better.

Comment: @Remou Besides the obvious maintainability benefits, are there other benefits of `SELECT * FROM table` over using the table directly?

Comment: Besides keeping calculations, parameters and only the used columns, queries become indispensable when you need to change a table name. I guess in that list, parameters are the main non-maintenance benefit. The thing is, like creation dates, by the time you wish you had used them, it is late to change.

Comment: Is it possible to have queries with parameters as the source for a form/report? Where will the value of the paremeter be taken from?

Comment: Yes, it is. The recordset can be set to a querydef.

Comment: And I pass the parameter value in code when I set the recordset to the querydef?

Comment: Doesn't work.  How do I get the value from the field in the table, please.

Comment: @Warwick Access should automatically recognize the fieldname, unless it contains a space (or some other special character). (BTW For this reason having fieldnames with such characters is a bad idea in Access). Try this: `Line1.Visible = Me("f 1") > 100`

Comment: @Warwick When you say it doesn't work, do you mean the line gets hidden? the line doesn't get hidden? is there a runtimne error? at what line? Please also post the code you are trying.